# CSS <div> doesn't align the text to the left even when there is space

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello there I try to align some text in a  container to the left but it won't work even when there is free space. As you can see there is some free space directly next to the image which isn't used for no reason. Right here I show you a picture and also the style. Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

[image]

```css
.text-wrapper-overview {
  position: inherit;
  left: 100px;
  width: 65%;
}

.user-name {
  position: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.last-message {
  position: inherit;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: small;
}

.timestamp-overview {
  position: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id={this.name} className="chat-overview" onClick={()=>this.renderChat()}>
  <img className="round-image" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/200"></img>
  <div className="text-wrapper-overview">
    <p className="user-name">{this.name}</p>
    <p className="last-message">{this.lastMessage.text}</p>
    <p className="timestamp-overview">{this.lastDate}</p>
  </div>
  <div className="notification">10+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your html structure?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with RENDERED HTML

Comment: Most likely it's due to the `left: 100px;` setting on `.text-wrapper-overview`  - try to reduce that. But it's hard to tell with the little information you gave...

Comment: What else information do you need. I really have no clue how to fix that. With reducing the left property the text will just get stuck in the image which doesn't fix the problem that the text won't align on the very left in the div

Comment: Have you tried position: relative?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
p.date {
text-align: right;
}
```

property this will align p text to right.

Read more here :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

Comment: I'm so sorry I meant the alignment to the left which doesn't work with the property you mentioned

Comment: Do you wants to align container to left or text to left ?

Comment: I want to align the text in the container to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included all of your styles to use as an example. But I would suggest looking into the [flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

```css
.chat-overview {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-wrapper-overview {
  position: inherit;
  left: 100px;
  width: 65%;
}

.user-name {
  position: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.last-message {
  position: inherit;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: small;
}

.timestamp-overview {
  position: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id={this.name} class="chat-overview">
  <img class="round-image" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/200"></img>
  <div class="text-wrapper-overview">
    <p class="user-name">{this.name}</p>
    <p class="last-message">{this.lastMessage.text}</p>
    <p class="timestamp-overview">{this.lastDate}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="notification">10+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I think learning how to handle flex is important but at the moment it will destroy a lot of the other formating I did on this project. I'm still really interested why it doesn't work the way I try to do it.

Comment: @TimFinmans I looked at it again...have you tried changing the `left: 100px` to 10px? I don't have all the styles that your images shows to test with., but my guess would be that `left: 100px` is "right-aligning" that `text-wrapper-overview`.